# SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am not able to find what is wrong with my syntax:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
conn.Open();
            
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Labeler_Email_For_Confirmation_Agents] (Id, Response) VALUES (" +  TempData["id"] + "  ,  " + Correctornot + ");");

cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I don't understand - what is my syntax error? `connstr` is my connection string and `Correctornot` is the value received from button , i.e button value

Comment: Use [parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) queries.

Comment: Check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If Response is of type varchar/string you need to surround the value with `'` :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO [dbo].[Labeler_Email_For_Confirmation_Agents] ( Id , Response ) VALUES ( " +  TempData["id"] + "  ,  '"+ Correctornot + "'  );" );
```

Saying that you should really be using parameters as best practice

Answer (score 1):

you need to add single quote around second parameter value to fix this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO [dbo].[Labeler_Email_For_Confirmation_Agents] ( Id , Response ) VALUES ( " +  TempData["id"] + "  ,  '"+ Correctornot + "'  );" );
```

But, apart from the fact that this code is open to sql injection attack, this code will still fail if text in Correctornot variable itself has single quote and is a big NO-NO

[check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to see sample code of how you can parameterised query

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Labeler_Email_For_Confirmation_Agents] (Id, Response) VALUES (" +  TempData["id"].ToString + "  ,  " + Correctornot.ToString + ");");
```